# Looping thru kubernetes commands

Tags: bash, kubernetes

I have a test.txt file that has bunch of kubernetes commands. It looks like:

```
kubectl get cm -o yaml | grep "test"
kubectl get pods
kubectl describe pod xxx
.
.
```

bash script read the test.txt and loop thru each command should executes.
However, when I run the script, it gives the following error.
Any ideas how to fix this?

> Error from server (NotFound): configmaps "|" not found
>
> Error from server (NotFound): configmaps "grep" not found
>
> Error from server (NotFound): configmaps """ not found

Here is the script:

```
in_file=test.txt

# Loop over each line
while read -r test_case; do
    "kubectl -n ${namespace} ${test_case}" 
    
done < "$in_file"
```

Comment: does the below answer work for you? if not, can you kindly post an update?

Answer (score 1):

Change your bash script to this:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat test.txt | xargs -I {} bash -c {}
```

Works like a treat:

```
{"apiVersion":"v1","data":{"api-key":"abc123","database-url":"postgresql://localhost/mydatabase"},"kind":"ConfigMap","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"example-config","namespace":"default"}}
    name: example-config
{"apiVersion":"v1","data":{"api-key":"abc123","database-url":"postgresql://localhost/mydatabase"},"kind":"ConfigMap","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"example-config2","namespace":"default"}}
    name: example-config2
{"apiVersion":"v1","data":{"api-key":"abc123","database-url":"postgresql://localhost/mydatabase"},"kind":"ConfigMap","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"example-config3","namespace":"default"}}
    name: example-config3
```

Got the idea from [here](https://coderwall.com/p/vsx0yg/bash-xargs-as-a-for-loop).
I wasn't sure if it'd work, but it did :)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
kubectl get cm -o yaml | grep "test"
```

should be changed to

```
kubectl get cm <your_cm_name> -o yaml | grep "test"
```

You are missing the name argument and that's why `kubectl` think the pipe character is the name of you configmap.

Comment: There are 45 configmaps, thats why I am grepping "test". 
Stand alone  ```kubectl get cm -o yaml | grep "test"```  works

Comment: Inclusion of $test_case inside the quotes makes it all part of the kubectl command.   There seems to be no reason for you to have quoted the kubectl command anyway; just remove the quotes.